# I need a search to match values that are stored as null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm doing a search query against a single table that passes in several variables and compares several fields. 
Like this:

```
          WHERE  a.callerfname LIKE @FName
                 AND a.callerlname LIKE @LName
                 AND a.callermname LIKE @MName
```

The form sends in % if no value is selected for one of the fields therefore that field matches all results.

One field is the `ProjectID` which is a Guid and may contain `null` values.
When I get a search with no project selected the form passes in the blank Guid (000000-000...) and I check for it in a `CASE` like this:

```
AND a.projectid = CASE WHEN  @ProjectId <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                       THEN  @ProjectId
                       ELSE a.projectid
                             END
```

The trouble is that if a row has a `NULL ProjectID` it will not match itself.
My question is what would a null value in a guid field match? Or how can I make projectid return all values if null the way and name would if compared to a %?

Comment: look at something liek this: `WHERE (column=@Parameter OR NULLIF(@Parameter,'%') IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL NULL is not equal to any value, and NULL is not equal to NULL.  You have to test for "IS NULL".  Or, you can apply an isnull(column, default value) to both sides of your test.  Either of these should work.  I don't work with guids much, so I'm sticking your empty guid value in the isNull condition since you need to keep the data types matching and i assume that's a valid guid value.

```
  AND ISNULL(a.projectid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = CASE WHEN @ProjectId <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN @ProjectId ELSE isnull(a.projectid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') END
```

Or

```
AND (a.projectid = CASE WHEN @ProjectId <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN @ProjectId ELSE a.projectid END) OR (a.projectid is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be your project filter. If parameter is an empty guid, all projects match; if not, only one (or none) matches.

```
WHERE (@ProjectId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
       OR a.projectid = @ProjectId)
```